# How protect public Laravel livewire property from manipulation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am mounting my component with an object `$form` which I need to access between requests.
The data in `$form` is not secret, but should not be tampered with so I would like to make it a `protected` property. Though only `public` properties are preserved between requests leaving it exposed to front end.

If possible, how can I prevent manipulation on this public property?

I tried a check

```
public function updating($key, $value)
{
    if($key === 'form') return;
}
```

But I don't think that really does anything.

Also, using sessions is not an alternative in my situation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to access $form in the frontend?

Comment: Don't know if this answers your question https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you have these options:

1. Do not store the data as public property, instead **just pass it to
   your view** in the `render()` method.

   ```
   public function render(){
      return view('Livewire.nameofyourview ', [
         'form' => YourDataSource::get()
      ]);
   }
   ```

   This will refetch the data on every interaction with your component. You can      access this in your template as before as `$form`.
   Make sure to remove `$form` as public property. Manipulating the $form data form client/user site isn't possible with this solution. [Docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#render-method)
2. Use **validation rules** if you need your user/client to manipulate the
   data, but  only ways you expect.

   ```
   protected $rules = [
       'form.name' => 'required|min:6',
       'form.email' => 'required|email',
   ];
   ```

   [Full Example](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation)
3. Use **Laravel cache** to preserve data between requests. This technique
   is useful if you can't refetch your data from the source, like when
   it was passed to your Livewire component as parameter (`<livewire:form-component :form="$form">`).

   ```
   /* Cache the data on component mount */
   public function mount($form)
   {
       Cache::set($this->id."_form", $form, 60*10);
   }

   public function someFunction()
   {
       /* read the data form cache, if you need it again */
       cache($this->id."_form");
   }
   ```